# I want to run aws-cli commands using cloudfomation

Tags: amazon-web-services

I can create/delete a cloudformation stack using aws-cli, but I want to reverse, like run an aws cli commands using cloudformation stack

Answer (score 0):

Try using any command in the following way:

```
"AWS::CloudFormation::Init" : {
    "configSets" : {
        "ascending" : [ "config1" , "config2" ],
        "descending" : [ "config2" , "config1" ]
    },
    "config1" : {
        "commands" : {
            "test" : {
                "command" : "echo \"$CFNTEST\" > test.txt",
                "env" : { "CFNTEST" : "I come from config1." },
                "cwd" : "~"
            }
        }
    },
    "config2" : {
        "commands" : {
            "test" : {
                "command" : "echo \"$CFNTEST\" > test.txt",
                "env" : { "CFNTEST" : "I come from config2" },
                "cwd" : "~"
            }
        }
    }
}
```